# How to ensure correct encoding in OData v4 Dynamic Properties

Tags: c#, odata

I'm writing an OData V4 service / Web API 2 with the latest OData NuGet packages. I have a problem I think is a formatting issue or maybe a configuration issue on the server but I am new to OData and WebAPI, so I am probably wrong.

The problem is as so:
If I call my OData service with patch where a non-us string like "Mølgaard" is contained both in a field that points to a declared property and in a dynamic property, I get in my patch method on my controller "Mølgaard" in the declared property, but in the dynamic properties I get the raw-value "M\u00f8lgaard". The expected behaviour is to get "Mølgaard" in both, and what I find very strange is that the dynamic properties seem to get handled differently than the declared POCO-properties.
I have tried this with a generated MS ODataClient bound to my service and also via a tool called Postman, in both instances I get into my Patch method with the same wrong value.

Being very new to OData, I have tried adding a new serializer as described here:
http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#06-03-costomize-odata-formatter
and from there modifications as described in the answer here:
[OData WebApi V4 .net - Custom Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53151390/odata-webapi-v4-net-custom-serialization)
I also found an example around using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.
In short, neither did help and I am guessing that neither are actually meant to solve this issue.

I started from a demo project I found here:
https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/XPO_how-to-implement-odata4-service-with-xpo

I have added an POCO class like so:

```
    public class OOrder : IDynamicProperties
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        // SomeText is the declared property and its value 
        // is then repeated in DynamicProperties with another name
        public string SomeText { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
    }

    // I do not know if I need this, I am using
    // it in a map function
    public interface IDynamicProperties
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> DynamicProperties { get; set; }
    }
```

And my config is pretty basic:

```
    public static class WebApiConfig {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
            config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
            ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = CreateODataModelBuilder();
            ODataBatchHandler batchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer);
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: null,
                model: modelBuilder.GetEdmModel(),
                batchHandler: batchHandler);
        }

        static ODataModelBuilder CreateODataModelBuilder()
        {
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataModelBuilder();
            var openOrder = builder.EntityType<OOrder>();
            openOrder.HasKey(p => p.ID);
            openOrder.Property(p => p.SomeText);
            openOrder.HasDynamicProperties(p => p.DynamicProperties);
            builder.EntitySet<OOrder>("OOrders");

            return builder;
        }
    }
```

And my patch function on my controller looks like this:

```
        [HttpPatch]
        public IHttpActionResult Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<OOrder> order)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest();

            using (UnitOfWork uow = ConnectionHelper.CreateSession()) {
                OOrder existing = getSingle(key, uow);
                if (existing != null) {
                    Order existingOrder = uow.GetObjectByKey<Order>(key);
                    order.CopyChangedValues(existing);
                    mapOpenWithDynamcPropertiesToPersisted(existing, existingOrder);
                    // Intentionally not storing changes for now
                    //uow.CommitChanges();
                    return Updated(existing);
                }
                else {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
        }

        private void mapOpenWithDynamcPropertiesToPersisted<TOpen, TPersisted>(TOpen open, TPersisted persisted) 
            where TPersisted : BaseDocument
            where TOpen: IDynamicProperties  {
            if (open != null && persisted != null && open.DynamicProperties != null && open.DynamicProperties.Any()) {
                XPClassInfo ci = persisted.ClassInfo;
                foreach (string propertyName in open.DynamicProperties.Keys) {
                    var member = ci.FindMember(propertyName);
                    if (member != null) {                            
                        object val = open.DynamicProperties[propertyName];
                        // Here, I have tried to deserialize etc
                        member.SetValue(persisted, val);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

After the call on order.CopyChangedValues(existing), the existing instance contains correctly encoded value in its "SomeText" property, but not in the corresponding Dynamic property.

Comment: You code will not work under three conditions 1) If int ID  is null.  Recommend changing int to int? to handle null 2) If ID is not a number.  Would use TryeParse 3) If IDictionary has duplicate keys.  Make sure you test if item is already in dictionary.

Comment: This seems like a weird comment @jdweng, it adds nothing in the form of an answer. Using an non-nullable int makes sense to me when it is a key to a table, Int is a type and does not carry nulls or anything else non-int. In regards to no 3: IDictionary is used here because it is a signature for dynamic properties in OData v4, I am using the Dictionary<string, object> implementation.

Comment: The database could have null values if nobody inserted values into database.

Answer (score 2):

I found somewhat of an answer and it has apparently to do with myself not reading properly the articles I mention in the question.
The answer seems to be an injected deserializer who uses an json converter to convert the dynamic properties, because they are apparently *always* in raw format.
My config is now as so:

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
            config.Count().Filter().OrderBy().Expand().Select().MaxTop(null);
            ODataBatchHandler batchHandler = new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer);
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: null,
                configureAction: builder => builder.AddService<IEdmModel>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => CreateODataModel())
                    .AddService<ODataBatchHandler>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, bb => new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer))
                    .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("ODataRoute", config))
                    .AddService<Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataSerializerProvider>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new MiTestSerializerProvider(sp))
                    .AddService<Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Deserialization.ODataDeserializerProvider>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new MiDynamicPropertiesDeserializerProvider(sp))
                );
        }
```

Where the deserializer is the important one in this context.
My beginning of a deserializer looks as so (it requires a provider/implementation coupling):

```
    public class MiDynamicPropertiesDeserializerProvider : DefaultODataDeserializerProvider
    {
        MiDynamicPropertiesDeserializer _edmSerializer;
        public MiDynamicPropertiesDeserializerProvider(IServiceProvider rootContainer) : base(rootContainer) {
            _edmSerializer = new MiDynamicPropertiesDeserializer(this);
        }

        public override ODataEdmTypeDeserializer GetEdmTypeDeserializer(IEdmTypeReference edmType) {
            switch (edmType.TypeKind()) { // Todo: Do I need more deserializers ?
                case EdmTypeKind.Entity: return _edmSerializer;
                default: return base.GetEdmTypeDeserializer(edmType);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MiDynamicPropertiesDeserializer : ODataResourceDeserializer {
        public MiDynamicPropertiesDeserializer(ODataDeserializerProvider serializerProvider) : base(serializerProvider) { }

        private static Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>> simpleTypeConverters = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>() {           
            { typeof(DateTime), d => new DateTimeOffset((DateTime)d)  } // Todo: add converters or is this too simple ?
        };

        public override void ApplyStructuralProperty(object resource, ODataProperty structuralProperty, IEdmStructuredTypeReference structuredType, ODataDeserializerContext readContext) {
            if (structuralProperty != null && structuralProperty.Value is ODataUntypedValue) {
                // Below is a Q&D mapper I am using in my test to represent properties
                var tupl = WebApplication1.Models.RuntimeClassesHelper.GetFieldsAndTypes().Where(t => t.Item1 == structuralProperty.Name).FirstOrDefault();
                if (tupl != null) {
                    ODataUntypedValue untypedValue = structuralProperty.Value as ODataUntypedValue;
                    if (untypedValue != null) {
                        try {
                            object jsonVal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(untypedValue.RawValue);
                            Func<object, object> typeConverterFunc;
                            if (jsonVal != null && simpleTypeConverters.TryGetValue(jsonVal.GetType(), out typeConverterFunc))
                            {
                                jsonVal = typeConverterFunc(jsonVal);
                            }
                            structuralProperty.Value = jsonVal;
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) { /* Todo: handle exceptions ? */  }
                    }
                }
            }
            base.ApplyStructuralProperty(resource, structuralProperty, structuredType, readContext);
        }
    }
```

Thanks to everyone who has used time on this, I hope someone else will find this info useful.